# Hammer.js fires extraneous pinchin/pinchout events

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, pinch, bug-reporting

Using this code in the JS pannel of the CodePen sample:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);

var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch({threshold: 0});
mc.add([pinch])
mc.on("pinch pinchin pinchout pinchstart pinchend", function(ev) {
    myElement.textContent += ev.type +" ";
});
```

and testing for the pinch event on Chrome on a PC with a Touch Screen, you will notice that pinchend is always followed by an extra "pinchin" event. The same happens when pinching out.

The sequence will go:

```
pinchstart pinch pinchin pinch pinchin... ...pinch pinchin pinch pinchend pinchin
```

Is this a bug or is this by design? Is this related to the 'ghost click'?

Comment: As a workaround I have added code in the Pinch listener that tracks the last Pinch event. If previous Pinch event was 'pinchend' then I ignore the the current pinchin or pinchout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "pinch" event alone or the other events (pinchin, pinchout, etc..), not both at the same time.

Just remove "pinch":

```
mc.on("pinchin pinchout pinchstart pinchend", function(ev) {
    myElement.textContent += ev.type +" ";
});
```